# how to make this faster?

Tags: c, matrix, optimization

I have a body of code that I need to be faster, any tips or solutions would be useful. Looking to have a higher amount of cache hits by re-ordering memory accesses to be as sequential as possible.

```
int elij, veci, prod, curr, next;
for(int j=0; j<mat.cols; j++){
    VSET(res,j,0);              // initialize res[j] to zero
    for(int i=0; i<mat.rows; i++){
      elij = MGET(mat,i,j); 
      veci = VGET(vec,i);
      prod = elij * veci;
      curr = VGET(res,j);
      next = curr + prod;
      VSET(res,j, next);        // add on the newest product
    }
  }
```

I was told that maybe switching cols and rows would be helpful because it avoids continually accessing memory that is farther away in cache, but im not sure how to do that.

This function is meant to perform a matrix transpose multiplied by a vector. any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: What is `MGET`? `VGET`? `mat`? `vec`? Please provide a [mcve] because there’s no way anyone can determine what these do, what the types are, how memory is accessed etc based on this piece alone. Speed also depends on CPU architecture and whatnot so this may very well be a way too broad a question

Comment: I believe this questions belongs to [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) once the OP provides a working code.

Comment: You need to describe the way you are going to measure the speed, what speed you are currently measuring that way and what speed you need to achieve. That information is necessary to propose changes which have a chance at actually improving things. Also optimisation questions are too broad if that information is not provided. I.e. extend this into an MRE (as already proposed by Sami) of the test program. Also provide some of the sample data you are going to use for measuring.

Answer (score 1):

On surface, this is the classic vector my matrix multiplication. Any decent compiler will optimize the code, provided it can see thru the getters/setters: VGET, MGET, VSET).

If you MUST use the wrappers, best approach will be to use 'inline' on the getters, setters (assuming they are not macros). If they are not required, consider removing them as they do not contribute much, and using v[i], etc. This will free the power of the optimizer to use vectorization, etc.